# ndk build with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, android-ndk

i'm building an cpp file that uses opencv library. I include cv.h and my Application.mk got

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := "C:\OpenCV2.1\lib\cxcore210.lib" "C:\OpenCV2.1\lib\highgui210.lib" "C:\OpenCV2.1\lib\cvaux210.lib"  "C:\taucs_full\lib\win32\libtaucs.lib"
```

but i cannot call any function , for example cvSaveImage. I looked through opencv directory and try to find cpp file that implements those functions but cannot find.
So how can I do it?

Comment: What is the error message when you try to call cvSaveImage?

Comment: undefined reference error, because opencv lib provide header files and lib file. Do you know about this lib? search through but no results.

Comment: Your `LOCAL_LDLIBS` lists the Windows versions of OpenCV libraries (_how do I know?_ Because they have `.lib` extension). To build your Android native library, you should first build OpenCV for Android, using NDK and its gcc toolchain. This will produce files like `libxccore210.a`, etc. You will add these files to `LOCAL_LDLIBS`. Note also, that this definition should be put in `Android.mk` file, not `Application.mk`!

Comment: @AlexCohn - question re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

Your `LOCAL_LDLIBS` lists the Windows versions of OpenCV libraries (*how do I know?* Because they have `.lib` extension). To build your Android native library, you should first build OpenCV for Android, using NDK and its gcc toolchain. This will produce files like `libcxcore210.a`, etc. You will add these files to `LOCAL_LDLIBS` (note that **lib** and **.a** are concealed):

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -Lc:/opencv2.1/libandroid -lcxcore210 -lhighgui210 -lcvaux210
```

Note also, that this definition should be put in `Android.mk` file, not `Application.mk`!